# Обратный счёт после добавления.(1 день, 7 часов, 1 минута и 32 секунды назад)

Tags: php

> Функция выдает "1 день 7 часов 1 минута 32 секунды назад". Как сделать
>   так, что если 1 день (24 часа) прошло, то вывод "1 день назад."; если
>   прошла неделя то "1 неделю назад" ...
>
> Коротко говоря, если не прошло одного дня, пусть выводит "7 часов 1 минута 32 секунды назад"; если же прошло то "1 день назад",  "2 недели назад" и т.д. ....

```
function showDate( $date ) // $date --> время в формате Unix time
{
    $stf      = 0;
    $cur_time = time();
    $diff     = $cur_time - $date;

    $seconds = array( 'секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд' );
    $minutes = array( 'минута', 'минуты', 'минут' );
    $hours   = array( 'час', 'часа', 'часов' );
    $days    = array( 'день', 'дня', 'дней' );
    $weeks   = array( 'неделя', 'недели', 'недель' );
    $months  = array( 'месяц', 'месяца', 'месяцев' );
    $years   = array( 'год', 'года', 'лет' );
    $decades = array( 'десятилетие', 'десятилетия', 'десятилетий' );

    $phrase = array( $seconds, $minutes, $hours, $days, $weeks, $months, $years, $decades );
    $length = array( 1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560, 315705600 );

    for ( $i = sizeof( $length ) - 1; ( $i >= 0 ) && ( ( $no = $diff / $length[ $i ] ) <= 1 ); $i -- ) {
        ;
    }
    if ( $i < 0 ) {
        $i = 0;
    }
    $_time = $cur_time - ( $diff % $length[ $i ] );
    $no    = floor( $no );
    $value = sprintf( "%d %s ", $no, getPhrase( $no, $phrase[ $i ] ) );

    $value = '';

    for (; $i >= 0; $diff %= $length[$i--]) {
    $no = floor($diff / $length[$i]);
    $value .= sprintf("%d %s ", $no, getPhrase($no, $phrase[$i]));
    }

    return $value . ' назад';
}

function getPhrase( $number, $titles ) {
    $cases = array( 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2 );

    return $titles[ ( $number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20 ) ? 2 : $cases[ min( $number % 10, 5 ) ] ];
}
```

Comment: А какое отношение имеет mysql к вопросу ?

Comment: А вообще попробуйте действия которые в последнем for выполнить только 1 раз

Comment: Ну выведет 1 день назад 2 недели назад ... а мне нужно через if сделать как то проверку если 1 день не прошло то 1 час 2 минут 12 секунд чтобы выдавала типа

Comment: Ну вот вызываю ее (не исправленную) от `time()-10000` отлично выдает '2 часа 46 минут 40 секунд  назад'. Как бы все правильно, одного дня не прошло вот она и выдала начиная с часов

Comment: mysql здесь точно не при чем. для отсчета типа "только что", "5 минут назад", "вчера" и т.д. обычно используют javascript, т.к. только он позволит вам менять надписи в реальном времени без обновления страницы. посмотрите расширение timeago. кстати, оно имеет русскую локализацию. https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago

Answer (score 2):

От большего к меньшему постройте каскад условий, примерно так:

```
if( $diff > 86400) {
    echo "N дней назад";
} else if( $diff > 3600) {
    echo "N часов назад";
} else if( $diff > 60) {
    echo "N минут назад";
} else {
    echo "N секунд назад";
}
```